nodejs_compat is not working on Cloudflare Pages
I deploy Remix to Cloudflare Pages with Remix official Cloudflare template.
All went well until I added jsonwebtoken package. It shows Could not resolve "crypto" as well as "stream".
This is the reproduction: https://github.com/gjc14/cannot-resolve-native-package-on-remix-cloudflare

I've added nodejs_compat on both wrangler.toml and Dashboard, and I could not add prfix node: cause these are used in the package. Does anyone has experience for fixing this issue?
Also tried NODE_VERSION setting in Cloudflare, but not working.
00:48:56.191    Detected the following tools from environment: nodejs@20.5.1, npm@9.6.7
00:48:56.192    Installing nodejs 20.5.1
00:48:56.266    nodejs 20.5.1 is already installed
...
00:49:31.771    ✘ [ERROR] 6 error(s) and 0 warning(s) when compiling Worker.
00:49:31.772    
00:49:31.772    
00:49:31.775    
00:49:31.777    ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "crypto"
00:49:31.777    
00:49:31.777        ../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:12:65:
00:49:31.777          12 │ ...KeyObject, createSecretKey, createPrivateKey } = require('crypto')
00:49:31.777             ╵                                                             ~~~~~~~~
00:49:31.777    
00:49:31.777      The package "crypto" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
00:49:31.777      Add the "nodejs_compat" compatibility flag to your Pages project and make sure to prefix the module name with "node:" to enable Node.js compatibility.

✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "crypto"
23:55:39.338    
23:55:39.338        ../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:12:65:
23:55:39.338          12 │ ...KeyObject, createSecretKey, createPrivateKey } = require('crypto')
23:55:39.338             ╵                                                             ~~~~~~~~
23:55:39.339    
23:55:39.339      The package "crypto" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
23:55:39.339      Add the "nodejs_compat" compatibility flag to your Pages project and make sure to prefix the module name with "node:" to enable Node.js compatibility.

// package.json
{
    "name": "name",
    "private": true,
    "sideEffects": false,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "remix vite:build",
        "deploy": "wrangler pages deploy ./build/client",
        "dev": "remix vite:dev",
        "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --cache --cache-location ./node_modules/.cache/eslint .",
        "start": "wrangler pages dev ./build/client",
        "typecheck": "tsc",
        "typegen": "wrangler types"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.1.1",
        "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.1.0",
        "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.1.0",
        "@remix-run/cloudflare": "^2.11.2",
        "@remix-run/cloudflare-pages": "^2.11.2",
        "@remix-run/react": "^2.11.2",
        "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
        "clsx": "^2.1.1",
        "framer-motion": "^11.3.30",
        "isbot": "^4.1.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
        "lucide-react": "^0.435.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "tailwind-merge": "^2.5.2",
        "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@cloudflare/workers-types": "^4.20240512.0",
        "@remix-run/dev": "^2.11.2",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.14",
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.20",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.4",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.4",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
        "eslint": "^8.38.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.38",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.4.4",
        "typescript": "^5.1.6",
        "vite": "^5.1.0",
        "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.1",
        "wrangler": "3.57.1"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=20.0.0"
    }
}

# wrangler.toml
compatibility_flags = ["nodejs_compat"]

[[services]]
binding = "DB"    # name of the binding in `env`
service = "another-worker"    # name of the worker in the dashboard

enter image description here
The way I import jsonwebtoken:
// auth.ts
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'


Try to set NODE_VERSION environment variable in cloudflare pages. Might be Cloudflare pages not supporting your node js version by default.

My problem was, I was importing dependency from "@remix-run/node", instead of
"@remix-run/cloudflare":
- import type { ActionFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
- import { json } from "@remix-run/node";
+ import { ActionFunction, json } from "@remix-run/cloudflare";


Hi but I do changed all @remix-run/node to @remix-run/cloudflare, as you could see in my package.json. Or you're saying that I will work if I use node?

Did you change it from "@remix-run/node" to "@remix-run/cloudflare" also in your source js / ts / jsx / tsx files?

Sure I did, but confirmed by remix community. Unfortunately the Cloudflare is picky to run nodejs on their server. The only way should be changing to different packages

Hi for people encountering this problem, it seems that cloudflare is not really supporting the config of the usage in this scenario. To fix this, I simply switch to crypto-js.
